# Vue mutating a property that is used as "v-model"

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Many issue like this but I cannot find my way. I simplified the code to explain my problem...
Just wanted a reusable feedback message to show with the result of the rest api using vuetity andsnackbar widget.
In the parent component:

```
<Feedback :active="hasFeedback" :msg="feedbackMsg" />
```

The Feedback component:

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="active" >
    {{ msg }}
    <v-icon @click="active = false">mdi-close-thick</v-icon>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: ["active", "msg"]
};
</script>
```

I tried to add computed property, methods, getter, setter but always got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your **active** prop to some prop in a data section of a component and use and change that prop in the data section.

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar v-model="isActive" >
    {{ msg }}
    <v-icon @click="isActive = false">mdi-close-thick</v-icon>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }, {
    msg: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: this.active
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this part is not correct: props: [active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }, "msg"],

Comment: Conclusion of this article: https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/ ... "This means that you can't use props with v-model"

Comment: Look about muitating props in the official docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly I tried it also but it's not working.

Comment: What error did you get after using isActive in the data section?